# Как сделать так, чтобы крайние элементы слайдера были видимы только наполовину?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

Есть у меня слайдер owl каруселька, хочу сделать так, чтобы крайние элементы были наполовину видимые, т.е. половина была видимой, а половина уходила за горизонт (чтобы юзер понимал, что в карусели есть еще элементы) - как это можно сделать?

```js
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
    itemsCustom: [[600,5],[500,4],[400,3],[300,2],[200,1]]
});
```

```css
.block {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: #888888;
}

.red {
    background: #FFCCCC;
}
.green {
    background: #CCFFCC;
}
.blue {
    background: #CCCCFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="block red">1</div>
    <div class="block green">2</div>
    <div class="block blue">3</div>
    <div class="block red">4</div>
    <div class="block green">5</div>
    <div class="block blue">6</div>
    <div class="block red">7</div>
    <div class="block green">8</div>
    <div class="block blue">9</div>
    <div class="block red">10</div>
    <div class="block green">11</div>
    <div class="block blue">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: во второй версии owl slider - http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/stagepadding.html

Answer (score 1):

```
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer:before {
    width: 40px;
    background: black;
    content: '';
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer:after {
    width: 40px;
    background: black;
    content: '';
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Можете попробовать сделать так. Черный цвет конечно же заменить или на другой цвет или на стрелочки например дополнительно указывающие что еще есть элементы.

Comment: боюсь, что при таком раскладе убогонько будет выглядеть..
http://jsfiddle.net/u918v9o9/8/

Comment: ну так это уже вопрос вашей стилизации этих частей) можете заменить их на картинки стрелочек прозрачные и на js делать так чтобы они появлялись только когда мышкой наводите на карусель. Сами решайте как вам лучше надо сделать то)

Comment: ну да - вы же надеюсь видите, что при таком подходе с отступами беда - меня интересует как сделать так, чтобы ровно половина слайда с каждой стороны смотрелось. впрочем, необходимый ответ уже дан выше